# How to propose a potential function in amortized analysis?

Tags: algorithm, amortized-analysis

I have read some posts about ***amortized analysis***, but I still have some question in understanding the ***potential method***.

The major problem lies in *how to develop a formal potential function*? And *how to evaluate the correctness of the potential function*?

For instance, there is a question:

> A sequence of n operations is performed on a data structure. The ith operation costs i if i is an exact power of 2, and 1 otherwise. Use a potential method to determine the amortized cost per operation.

Adopting potential function, we should first propose a potential function: 
[image]. Someone tells me that this is very intuitive, but I cannot come up with this even after several hours.....

I find there is a similar question:

[need to find the amortized cost of a sequence using the potential function method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480109/need-to-find-the-amortized-cost-of-a-sequence-using-the-potential-function-metho)

However, I think the answer is about the *account method*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

The term `k` increases every time `k` increases (obviously), and it increases by `1`.

The term `2^ceiling(Lg(k))` increases every time `k` reaches a new power of `2`, and it increases by `i/2`.

Comment: Thanks. Now my understanding is that every time when `k` is a power of `2`, it has to pay `k` units of fee. Therefore, we can amortized those `k` into the previous `k/2` units. In this way, we develop such a potential function which has a constant `2`.

Comment: Yep, you get it. You pay 1 every time and an extra amortized 1 (i.e. on average).